# MFP 8 - Stop Push Notification

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

In MFP 8, I sent push notification with wrong text in PRODUCTION, How can we stop that since all the user doesn't receive notifications immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A client cannot cancel or recall the push notification once dispatched. You should review the Push notification payload carefully before dispatch.